# NLP / ML Python: variation of topic modeling + summarization? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, summarization, gpt-3

New to NLP and Machine learning. Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction:

I'm looking to create a function that takes 2 inputs.

-an array of strings (english sentences of varying relation to one another. but for these purposes let's just assume they're totally unrelated sentences)

-a "topic" string.

The function then returns a coherent paragraph / essay about the indicated "topic," using ONLY the available sentences.

Seems like some flavor of topic-modeling and summarization, except the function writes using only the predetermined array of strings.

Any thoughts as to what libraries or techniques I should investigate?

Thanks!

Comment: So in essence, GPT-3 or similar is only allowed to change the order of the array? Also, around how large is the array?

Comment: Yeah that's a good way of looking at it! Not to complicate it needlessly at this point, but parsing sentences into coherent sentence-fragments is also fine.

Let's say the array is 1000 sentences, within which you might find several "topics."